# MYSQL - Join most recent matching record from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables that look like this:

Table: cases

id
name
status
case_no

Table: notes

id
case_id
note_date
notes

I'd like to be able to create a query that grabs the data from the cases table and only the most recent entry from the notes table for each row in the cases table. So far I'm having no luck at all.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will return only the cases with notes attached:

```
SELECT c.*,
       x.*
  FROM CASES c
  JOIN NOTES x ON x.case_id = c.case_id
  JOIN (SELECT n.case_id,
               MAX(n.note_date) AS max_note_date
          FROM NOTES n
      GROUP BY n.case_id) y ON y.case_id = x.case_id
                           AND y.max_note_date = x.note_date
```

If you want all cases, regardless if they have a note attached:

```
   SELECT c.*,
          x.*
     FROM CASES c
LEFT JOIN NOTES x ON x.case_id = c.case_id
     JOIN (SELECT n.case_id,
                  MAX(n.note_date) AS max_note_date
             FROM NOTES n
         GROUP BY n.case_id) y ON y.case_id = x.case_id
                              AND y.max_note_date = x.note_date
```

Comment: Thank you! I've created a detailed tutorial based on your answer here: http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/17/

Comment: Your 2nd example does not work as expected for me. If there is no matching entry in `NOTE` the `CASE` record gets lost. Do you know why this could be? I tried your solution in my query with multiple JOINs of that kind. So I also added a table editor and try to fetch the newest editor.

Answer (score 5):

```
    SELECT *
      FROM cases c
INNER JOIN notes n ON n.case_id = c.id
                  AND n.id = (SELECT MAX(id)
                                FROM notes
                               WHERE case_id = c.id)
```

Also it is a common practice to keep the pointer to the last note id directly in `cases` table and support it with trigger

Comment: Thanks for the lighting fast replies! Keeping the pointer to the last note in the cases table makes a lot of sense.

Comment: ... and a group by c.id in the end did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having same problem recently and this forum has helped me a lot but I found the OMG Ponies answer isn't complete. It works for those cases with notes but it doesn't for cases without notes which is my issue.
My answer is similar but instead joining the group query with notes, I join it with cases.

It would be:

```
SELECT c.*, x.*
FROM CASES c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT n.case_id, MAX(n.note_date) AS max_note_date
               FROM NOTES n
               GROUP BY n.case_id) y ON y.case_id = c.case_id
    LEFT JOIN NOTES x ON x.case_id = c.case_id AND x.note_date=y.max_note_date
```

It's also valid to get just cases with notes removing one left keyword or both