# MySQL get most recent events on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

This might not be possible but would be amazingly awesome if it were.  I have the following basic table structure:

```
groups
 group_id
 other_stuff

users
 user_id
 other_stuff

users_to_groups
 user_id
 group_id
 other_stuff

events
 event_id
 group_id (where the event belongs)
 other_stuff
```

*events is actually a set of tables for the various actions a user can perform on the site.*

I would like to be able to perform a query on of the tables and have it return a result something like:

```
event_type        event_id               info_columns ...

 user_join     user_to_group_id
 photo_upload    photo_id
 comment        comment_id
```

where the value in the event_type column would be one generated by the query based on the table name of the source content.

I know I can do this using multiple queries and then piecing them together in PHP, but I was thinking that maybe there is a way to do it entirely in MySQL.  Is something like this even possible?  If so, what are the basic steps to make it happen?

Comment: If you add info on where the `comment` and `photo` data are stored, yes. Also, what are `user_join` and `user_to_group_id`? Other fields? In which table? Or a user that belongs to a group is automatically considered as having joined an event that belongs to same group?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a number of select statements, and you get the data you want in each, then of course you can join them.

Others have asked similar questions, [mysql-join-most-recent-matching-record-from-one-table-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869426/mysql-join-most-recent-matching-record-from-one-table-to-another)

Now, given you're only asking for the latest event. your pseudo code goes

```
select <userinfo>
from users
  join groups
    on user=group
  join (select lastest event by group
        from events
       ) as tmp
    on group=tmp
```

That way you do 1 query, you hand off that work to the database