# Left Join to most recent record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Games and Scores:

games has a primary key ID

Scores has game_id which references games.id and created on among other fields.

i am attempting to adapt the second example in the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869426/mysql-join-most-recent-matching-record-from-one-table-to-another) to fit my needs.

```
  SELECT g.*,
       s.*
  FROM GAMES g
  LEFT JOIN SCORES s ON s.game_id = g.id
  JOIN (SELECT n.game_id,
               MAX(n.created_on) AS max_score_date
          FROM SCORES n
      GROUP BY n.game_id) y ON y.game_id = s.game_id
                           AND y.max_score_date = s.created_on
```

it almost works, it gets the most recent entry in the score table for each game. however it only returns games which have a corresponding entry in the score table. and i need it to return all games in the table reguardless of if they have a entry in the score table. which from reading the previously cited question i assumed that the left join would accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  g.*, s.*
FROM
  GAMES g
LEFT JOIN
(
    SCORES s
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      n.game_id,  MAX(n.created_on) AS max_score_date
    FROM
      SCORES n
    GROUP BY
      n.game_id
  )
    y
      ON  y.game_id        = s.game_id
      AND y.max_score_date = s.created_on
)
    ON s.game_id = g.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional left outer join:

```
SELECT g.*, s.*
FROM GAMES g LEFT JOIN
     SCORES s
     ON s.game_id = g.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT n.game_id,  MAX(n.created_on) AS max_score_date
      FROM SCORES n
      GROUP BY n.game_id
     ) y
     ON y.game_id = s.game_id AND y.max_score_date = s.created_on
```

This version should do what you want:

```
select g.*, s.*
from (select g.*,
             (select max(created_on) as maxcreatedon
              from scores s
              where s.game_id = g.game_id
             ) as maxcreatedon
      from games g
     ) g left outer join
     scores s
     on s.game_id = g.game_id and
        s.created_on = g.maxcreatedon
```

Comment: That fixes one problem but creates another. while it is getting all of the games regardless of if there is a corresponding record in the scores table, it is also returning all of the records in the score table rather than just the newest one based on the created_on time stamp.