# msaccess join most recent matching record from one table to another with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

Expanding upon answer on [msaccess join most recent matching record from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765511/msaccess-join-most-recent-matching-record-from-one-table-to-another/31765734)

```
SELECT c.Tag, c.DateCreated AS most_recent, c.Comment, c.Author
FROM
    (
        SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate 
        FROM Comments 
        GROUP BY Tag
    ) AS md
    INNER JOIN
    Comments AS c
        ON c.Tag = md.Tag AND c.DateCreated = md.MaxDate
```

How do I use multiple criteria / n+1 criteria to get the result eg: I want to use tag, critera1 and criteria2 as a single composite key to query the status and comment tables.

**EDIT**: I've modified the question as what I Was originally asking apparently could not be done by storing the source data in a single table, so I'll ask another question with the data separated into separate tables. This question has been modified to match the answer given by @DonJewett

Table - Result

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
| ID |  Tag   | Criteria1 | Criteria2 |  DateCreated   |   Comment   | Author |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
|  6 | TAG001 | ghi       | jkl       | 25-July-2015   | Something6  | AQ     |
|  8 | TAG001 | mno       | pqr       | 23-July-2015   | Something8  | BV     |
| 13 | TAG002 | abc       | abc       | 22-June-2015   | Something13 | BV     |
| 14 | TAG001 | abc       | def       | 06-August-2015 | Something14 | AB     |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

The tables I have:

Status Table

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|  Tag   |   Status    | Criteria1 | Criteria2 |   DateStatus   |
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| TAG001 | Not Started | abc       | def       | 04-August-2015 |
| TAG001 | Complete    | ghi       | jkl       | 04-August-2015 |
| TAG001 | Complete    | mno       | pqr       | 02-August-2015 |
| TAG002 | Not Started | abc       | abc       | 02-August-2015 |
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comments Table:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
| ID |  Tag   | Criteria1 | Criteria2 |  DateCreated   |   Comment   | Author |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | TAG001 | abc       | def       | 22-July-2015   | Something1  | JS     |
|  3 | TAG001 | abc       | def       | 23-July-2015   | Something3  | AM     |
|  6 | TAG001 | ghi       | jkl       | 25-July-2015   | Something6  | AQ     |
|  8 | TAG001 | mno       | pqr       | 23-July-2015   | Something8  | BV     |
| 12 | TAG002 | abc       | abc       | 20-June-2015   | Something12 | AZ     |
| 13 | TAG002 | abc       | abc       | 22-June-2015   | Something13 | BV     |
| 14 | TAG001 | abc       | def       | 06-August-2015 | Something14 | AB     |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

I tried using AND, but it didn’t work.

```
SELECT c.Tag, c.DateCreated AS most_recent, c.Comment, c.Author
FROM
    (
        SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate 
        FROM Comments 
        GROUP BY Tag
    ) AS md
    INNER JOIN
    Comments AS c
        ON c.Tag = md.Tag AND c.DateCreated = md.MaxDate AND status.critera1 = c.criteria1 AND status.criteria2 = c.criteria2
```

**COMPLETE ANSWER:**

MaxCommentDateQuery

```
SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate, Criteria1, Criteria2
FROM Comments
GROUP BY Tag, Criteria1, Criteria2;
```

ResultQuery

```
SELECT c.Tag, c.DateCreated AS most_recent, c.Comment, c.Author
FROM MaxCommentDateQuery AS md INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON (md.Tag = c.Tag) AND (md.MaxDate = c.DateCreated);
```

ResultQuery (now with Status)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM Status
INNER JOIN (MaxCommentDateQuery AS md
INNER JOIN Comments AS c
ON (md.Tag = c.Tag) AND (md.MaxDate = c.DateCreated) AND (c.criteria1 = md.criteria1) AND (c.criteria2 = md.criteria2))
ON (Status.Tag = c.Tag) AND (Status.Criteria1 = c.Criteria1) AND (Status.Criteria2 = c.Criteria2);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to expand my query to use multiple criteria. ie: tag, criteria1, criteria2

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: how is it not a question? I had a query which used a single criteria, now i want to use multiple...

Comment: I've edited question to include what i tried.

Comment: "I want to use multiple criteria" is not a question, it is a statement. I could say, "You should try using multiple criteria," but you wouldn't consider that an answer, would you? If you want a a specific answer, we need a specific question.

Comment: OK I've edited my question. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the Status table in your query, so you can not use it in your query. I would suggest breaking your subquery out into its own separate query, and then you will be able to edit using the UI.

**MaxCommentDateQuery**

```
SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate 
    FROM Comments 
    GROUP BY Tag
```

**ResultQuery**

```
SELECT c.Tag, c.DateCreated AS most_recent, c.Comment, c.Author
FROM MaxCommentDateQuery AS md
INNER JOIN Comments AS c
    ON c.Tag = md.Tag AND c.DateCreated = md.MaxDate
```

Once you have these broken out, you will be able to add Status to the ResultQuery using the UI. Join on Tag and then you should be able use Status fields in your criteria.

**Version 1**

This is a composite key of Tag,Criteria1,Criteria2 joining Comments and Status. The result will be limited to the Maximum comment date. You may find this limits your results too much.

ResultQuery (now with Status)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Status INNER JOIN (MaxCommentDateQuery AS md INNER JOIN Comments AS c 
ON (md.MaxDate = c.DateCreated) AND (md.Tag = c.Tag)) 
ON (Status.Criteria2 = c.Criteria2) 
    AND (Status.Criteria1 = c.Criteria1) 
    AND (Status.Tag = c.Tag);
```

**Version 2**

If you need the criteria associated with the max comment date, use this version:

MaxCommentDateQuery (now with status)

```
SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate, Criteria1, Criteria2
FROM Comments
GROUP BY Tag, Criteria1, Criteria2;
```

ResultQuery (now with Status)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM Status
INNER JOIN (MaxCommentDateQuery AS md
INNER JOIN Comments AS c
ON (md.Tag = c.Tag) AND (md.MaxDate = c.DateCreated) 
     AND (c.criteria1 = md.criteria1) AND (c.criteria2 = md.criteria2))
ON (Status.Tag = c.Tag) AND (Status.Criteria1 = c.Criteria1) 
     AND (Status.Criteria2 = c.Criteria2);
```

Comment: Tried to build the query within the UI and was not successful. Running the ResultQuery (expanded) didn't work as it asked for a value

Comment: SELECT ResultQuery.most_recent, ResultQuery.Tag, ResultQuery.Comment, ResultQuery.Author, Comments.Criteria1, Comments.Criteria2
FROM MaxCommentDateQuery INNER JOIN ResultQuery ON (ResultQuery.most_recent = MaxCommentDateQuery.MaxDate) AND (MaxCommentDateQuery.Tag = ResultQuery.Tag), Comments INNER JOIN Status ON (Comments.Tag = Status.Tag) AND (Comments.Criteria2 = Status.Criteria2) AND (Comments.Criteria1 = Status.Criteria1); @DonJewett I managed to get this, but the results are repeated three times. I think I need to use distinct on tag, criteria1 and criteria2 somehow?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ResultQuery.most_recent, ResultQuery.Tag, ResultQuery.Comment, ResultQuery.Author, Comments.Criteria1, Comments.Criteria2
FROM MaxCommentDateQuery INNER JOIN ResultQuery ON (MaxCommentDateQuery.Tag = ResultQuery.Tag) AND (MaxCommentDateQuery.MaxDate = ResultQuery.most_recent), Comments INNER JOIN Status ON (Comments.Criteria1 = Status.Criteria1) AND (Comments.Criteria2 = Status.Criteria2) AND (Comments.Tag = Status.Tag); This still displays three repeated.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ResultQuery.most_recent, ResultQuery.Tag, ResultQuery.Comment, ResultQuery.Author
FROM MaxCommentDateQuery INNER JOIN ResultQuery ON (MaxCommentDateQuery.Tag = ResultQuery.Tag) AND (MaxCommentDateQuery.MaxDate = ResultQuery.most_recent), Comments INNER JOIN Status ON (Comments.Criteria1 = Status.Criteria1) AND (Comments.Criteria2 = Status.Criteria2) AND (Comments.Tag = Status.Tag);
But if i don't have criteria1 or 2 as part of select query it seems to work. But i need to see criteria1 and 2.... @Don Jewett

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it should work, but it doesn't. It returns zero results....

Comment: I'm not surprised. Each INNER JOIN means the two joined tables must match or that record is not displayed. Your options are 1) fewer joins or 2) outer joins, and/or 3) field criteria. If you double-click the join lines, you will get options for three kinds of joins. You might start with only one join between Comments (C) and Status on Tag. I don't really understand your result data set in your question. You probably need to explain exactly what fields/rows show up from which tables and why. I don't know what Criteria1/Criteria2 means, so I don't know why you would or wouldn't join them.

Comment: Tag, Criteria1 and Criteria2 form a composite key, but I was curious as to whether I could keep all the data in a single table, for other records which don't have Criteria1 and Criteria2 or might only have one. This is why the result set looks the way it does. I would assume the solution would be simpler if all records had all three field values filled out.

Comment: This seems like a classic many-to-many. It would better to use well-established design patterns, because the problems associated are not new, having much research behind them. If you put it all in one table with repeated values, you lose much of the gain of having relational data in the first place.

Comment: While I can appreciate using well established design patterns, I don't understand why I would need to in this instance. If I was to create four separate queries: 1) tag 2) tag and crit1 3) tag and crit2 4) tag , crit1 and crit2, then just union the results, to make each query simpler but still end up with the result I want.

Comment: I think the issue now is that MaxCommentDate query only uses tag, not tag, crit1 and crit2. I tried trimming my tables to have only tag and crit1. The query worked but I only saw one value for tag001 with crit1 of ghi as this was the most recent comment.

Comment: I've revised my question to include where I am at right now.

Comment: If you copy / paste the complete answer from my question, I'll mark you as the correct answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.Tag, c.DateCreated AS most_recent, c.Comment, c.Author
FROM
    (
        SELECT Tag, MAX(DateCreated) AS MaxDate 
        FROM Comments 
        GROUP BY Tag
    ) AS md
    INNER JOIN
    Comments AS c
        ON c.Tag = md.Tag AND c.DateCreated = md.MaxDate
    INNER JOIN
    status AS s
        ON s.critera1 = c.criteria1 AND s.criteria2 = c.criteria2
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Then access selects "= md" when I close dialog box.