# How to get the most recent article date for each category

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `articles` table and a `categories` table like this:

```
 articles
-----------------------------------------------
| id | datetime | title | categoryid | status |
-----------------------------------------------

 categories
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
```

I need to get the most recent articles date from each category in a select, like:

```
 result
----------------------------------------------------------
| category id | category name | most recent article date | 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The result must contain all categories + most recent article (with status = 0) date for each category.

Its must result exactly like `select * from categories` PLUS a new row showing the `datetime` of the most recente article of the category **BUT ONLY IF THE ARTICLE STATUS IS 0**.

Is that clear?

The reason I need that is because I'm trying to make a dynamic sitemap and I need the time of the latest article to each category to show on `<lastmod>` tag for the categories listing.

```
$sql = mysql_query(".....?......");

while ($string = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.url.com/<?echo $string['id'];?>/<?echo generate_seo_link($string['name']);?>/</loc>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <lastmod><? echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($string['date'])); ?></lastmod>
    </url>
<?}
```

Comment: What SQL statement have you tried?  Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869426/mysql-join-most-recent-matching-record-from-one-table-to-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE2** To accomodate `status`

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name, MAX(a.datetime) most_recent
  FROM articles a RIGHT JOIN
       categories c ON a.categoryid = c.id
 WHERE a.status IS NULL OR a.status = 0
 GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Output

```
| ID |      NAME |  RECENT_DT |
-------------------------------
|  1 | Category1 | 2013-03-19 |
|  2 | Category2 | 2013-03-17 |
|  3 | Category3 |     (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40efd/2)**

And on a side note

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are
>   [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)
>   or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Here is a good [PDO
>   tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Great! It Works. Just one more thing. I have some categories that dont have articles yet, but i would like to list them too. Is that possible? I dont want to bother you. If you dont answer me i will understand. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's possible and it is as easy as changing `LEFT` join to `RIGHT`, or we could've rewrite it with `LEFT` join swapping tables. See updated answer and sqlfiddle.

Comment: Its perfect now, peterm! Thank alot for you help.

Comment: peterm, im facing another problem, i had to add a new row on articles called "status" and the result must include only dates of articles wich status is 0. Any chances to do that?

Comment: It's not a good practice to change the question and unaccept the answer that completely covered your original question. But anyway see updated answer and sqlfiddle.

Comment: Really sorry. Thank you peterm.